# Calling self-defined closure in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, block, typedef, type-alias

In **objective-c** I could define my own block type:

```
typedef void (^myBlock)(id param1, id param2, BOOL param3);
```

then define the block body somewhere else(e.g. another class) to do something with passed values like:

```
myBlock block = ^(id param1, id param2, BOOL param3) { 
 if (param3){
   NSLog("parameters:%@,%@",param1,param2)
 }};
```

To do the same thing in **Swift** I defined my block using `typealias`:

```
typealias myBlock = (param1:AnyObject, param2:AnyObject, param3:Bool) -> ()
```

but I couldn't simply call it like:

```
let block: myBlock = {param1,param2,param3 in 
 if (param3){
     print(param1,param2)
 }}
```

and there was a warning:

> Initialization of immutable value 'block' was never used; consider
>   replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.

How can I call `myBlock` and define it's body in Swift?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your declaration. But as the word tells you, you are just *declaring* something and not calling. So the closure is not called anywhere.

Try this one

```
typealias myBlock = (param1:AnyObject, param2:AnyObject, param3:Bool) -> ()

let block: myBlock = {(param1,param2,param3) in 
 if (param3){
     print(param1,param2)
 }}

block(param1: 1,param2: 2,param3: true)
```

You have to replace the actual parameter with your values of course. Works like a charm as you can see in the playground screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the warning appears because you didn't use "block" variable anywhere in your code.

After declared "block" variable, try to use it somewhere in your code.